# How to substitute dlopen() in Android Nougat?

Tags: android, android-ndk, dlopen

I have an NDK app which can be extended via plugins which are loaded via `dlopen`. This used to work fine but it no longer works with Android N. As stated in the [developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk), `dlopen` is now officially abandoned:

> Starting in Android 7.0, the system prevents apps from dynamically linking against non-NDK libraries, which may cause your app to crash. This change in behavior aims to create a consistent app experience across platform updates and different devices.
>   ...
>   All apps generate a runtime error when they call an API that is neither public nor temporarily accessible. **The result is that System.loadLibrary and dlopen(3) both return NULL**, and may cause your app to crash.

I have seen that there is a [hack](https://github.com/avs333/Nougat_dlfunctions) that simply manually implements `dlopen` and `dlsym` for Android. This seems to work for Android N but of course nobody can tell how long this is still going to work.

That's why I am thinking about changing my plugin design into something that is officially supported and is future-proof. The most obvious choice would be the use Android's Service API and simply distribute my plugins as separate APKs that implement a Service.

However, I don't really like that idea since I'm using the NDK and I don't think that the Service API is available for the NDK. Of course, I could create a Service in Java and then use JNI to integrate it with my C code but this is of course not a very elegant solution.

That's why I'd like to ask what's the recommended way to support plugins which were previously `dlopen`-based in Android N? Is there an alternative route or am I forced to use the Service API now?

Comment: "I have seen that there is a hack" - are you sure? I think they only support `dlopen`ing an already loaded library so this won't work in your use-case. Reimplementing `dlopen` from scratch, with blackjack an^W^W symbol resolution and stuff, would be a major undertaking.

Comment: Oh, right, looking at the code this really seems to just do the trick for libraries that are already loaded. Too bad :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record; this was discussed in the android-ndk google group/mailing list, and it turned out that `dlopen` wasn't the culprit for the original poster at all:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/hhUv1mg3c_A/a5BbRtr-AwAJ

> Oops, sorry, actually, dlopen() is still working fine on Android 7.0. I was getting 
>   the following error message:

```
Detected problems with app native libraries (please consult log for detail): 
foobar.so: text relocations
```

The wording in the developer documentation was clarified further:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/hhUv1mg3c_A/eIKHZZcDBAAJ

> I guess the wording does technically make it sound like you're now [sic: read not] allowed to link to your own libraries. That definitely is not the case. The policy is that your cannot link to or dlopen private system libraries (anything in /system/lib that is not in the NDK).